# LinearLayout height in Android

Tags: android

In one LinearLayout there are many LinearLayouts nested and i want every one of them to share the screen space equally so the whole screen is filled and there is no free space on the screen vertically.
Any ides on how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each nested Linear has the:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

XML atrributes, and the root one (which holds them) has of course an

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent" .
```